# Display jQuery $.ajax 503 error response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display the response of a file that responds with an 503 error.

```
function netbootupdate() {


$("#netbootstatus").html('Updating..'); 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'clientarea.php',
    data: 'action=productdetails&id=' + $('#serverid').val() + '&modop=custom&a=netbootset&netbootid=' + $('#netbootid').val() + '&root=' + $('#root').val(),
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#netbootstatus").html(data);
      $("#status").html(''); 
    },
    error: function(data) {
      $("#status").html(data);
      $('#status').addClass('errorbox');
    }
    });
}
```

For some reason data doesn't give me the content of the reply.

Comment: why are you placing `data` in quotes? it's a variable name. Also, "data" should, in-fact, be `XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown` for arguments so you can get more details about the error returned.

Comment: Ah sorry ... yes, data wasn't in quotes in my code, just set it to something static a second ago to make sure it outputs in the right place. XMLHttpRequest and errorThrown are empty. textStatus responds with error. But I want to get it to display the HTML response.

Comment: Are you sure they're empty? The former should be an object with [properties that are accessible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah, how would I get the responseText to print?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.status` (assuming that was the name of the argument) -- please [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778363/display-jquery-ajax-503-error-response/4778467#4778467)

Comment: Great! Thanks: This works: error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#status").html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      $('#status').addClass('errorbox');
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   // ...
   // [other arguments]
   // ...
   error: function(xmlReq, txtStatus, errThrown){
     $('#status').text(xmlReq.responseText).addClass('errorBox');
   }
});
```

I think that's what you're going for, though not sure. Either way, the `xmlReq` (as I've named it) has [several properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) associated with it you can access and reference.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, In some browser, XHR refuse to pass data over when the status is anything but 2xx, 3xx. If you do need the data of a 503 response, try to rewrite the HTTP status code on server side.

In `complete(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)` callback, you may check `textStatus` for string `error` to detect 503. (Oh I just realized you already know that)

ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**Edit:** Use `complete()` instead of `success()` to catch all of the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I have a web service that I force to throw a 503 Error when the database is unavailable. It correctly returns a HTTP 503 response code, but in my client-side script the AJAX Response code returned is 500 (server error). You might like to have a generic 5** response code handler, rather than a specific 503, so you can catch all server-related issues. This is what I ended up doing.