# ajax jsonp request 503 response

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display jQuery $.ajax 503 error response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778363/display-jquery-ajax-503-error-response)

I am making a call to an api which is a bit temoermental. Alot of the time it is responding with a 503. My problem is that when this happens it none of the functions (complete, error, success) are triggered. I am looking for a way to log this in my code. Any ideas greatly appreciated

```
    $.ajax ({
      url      : engine.getQuery(), 
      dataType : 'jsonp',
      success  : entErrorFunction,
      complete : entErrorFunction,
      error    : entErrorFunction
    });

    var entErrorFunction = function(){
      console.log('test2');
    };
```

Comment: You should use search more carefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778363/display-jquery-ajax-503-error-response

Comment: Try adding a timeout. JSONp doesn't really have proper error handling since it is a `<script>` tag not real AJAX.

Comment: Your problem is that at the time you access `entErrorFunction`, it has no value yet. Assign the function before you make the call to `$.ajax`. Also note that `error` is not invoked for JSONP: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 1):

The following works, with JQuery 1.5+

```
    $.ajax ({ 
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
       statusCode: {
          503: function() {
          alert("API Error");
          }
       }
    });
```

**[(Reference)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Comment: I'm afraid not, the complete function isn't being triggered

Comment: If you are using jquery 1.5+, use the statusCode property. See edited answer.